# React Native Bulid Failed

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

[image]

Above error is coming when I am trying to create a build with Android, in React Native, this is my Package file https://github.com/davekedar/qp10nov/blob/master/package.json

and my app/build.gradle is as below

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal 
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.qualpros"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
    compile project(':tipsi-stripe')
    compile project(':react-native-paypal')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-orientation')
    compile project(':react-native-keep-awake')
    compile project(':react-native-video')
    compile project(':react-native-fs')
    compile project(':react-native-image-resizer')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.17.0"
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Above error may be because of the package I have installed, please try to solve this error, I will be thankful

Comment: I'm not familiar with React Native, but is there another build.gradle file in your project somewhere? I think you may be missing a maven repository.

Comment: I see that you are using onesignal
check that in your android/build.gradle you have
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal 
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

Comment: yes I am using onesignal

Comment: Yes, I know you are, but I ask if you have that in your android/build.gradle because in your previous question I didn't see it and it's part of the setup instruction from onesignal

Comment: this is app/build.gradle https://github.com/davekedar/qp10nov/blob/master/android/app/build.gradle

Comment: this is android/build.gradle https://github.com/davekedar/qp10nov/blob/master/android/build.gradle

Comment: Have you linked everything? `react-native link`.

Comment: Yes I have linked everything

Comment: I fixed your project, but it took at while, there is some stuff that need to be changed, I posted it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you shared your repository in the comments of the question I found out a couple of issues.

1. first you're using an old version of tipsi-strip, upgrade it in your package.json

change

> "tipsi-stripe": "^5.6.0",

to

> "tipsi-stripe": "^6.0.1",

and run

> npm install

or

> yarn install

if using yarn

2. In your app/build.gradle

you need to delete

> compile project(':react-native-onesignal')

Is not needed because you are using onesignal gradle plugin.

3. (Optional) your braintree version can be updated

from

> implementation "com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.17.0"

to

> implementation "com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.18.1"

4. you need to add plugins repository to your gradle.build because you're using opensignal gradle plugin

   ```
   ...

   repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }

   ...
   ```
5. You need to add onesignal gradle plugin to your classpath, also remove that dependency of build 2.2

   ```
   ...
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
   ...
   ```
6. add this at the end of your android/build.gradle

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
    firebaseVersion = "16.0.4"
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.0.4"
}

7. Add this in the section allprojects of your android/build.gradle

   ```
   allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Add jitpack repository (added by tipsi-stripe)
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.fabric.io/public" }
        google()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
         configurations.all {
                // #PlayServicesGate — March, 20 2018
                resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
                force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5'
                force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:+'
                force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
                force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
                force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
                force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:16.0.1'
                force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:16.2.0'

                // #FBSDKGate — August, 31 2018
                force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
            }
        }}
    }
   ```
8. in your AndroidManifest.xml

delete the following

```
-      <activity
-        android:name=".MainActivity"
-        android:label="OneSignal Example"
-        android:launchMode="singleTop"> <!-- Add this attribute to your main activity -->
-      </activity>
```

and modify the following

```
<activity
         android:name=".MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
+       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
+       android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

Also delete the following:

```
-      android:allowBackup="false"
```

your app should compile now.

> ./gradlew clean
>
> ./gradlew assembleDebug